# Laravel database not configured only after login/logout when I use the remember_token

Tags: laravel-5

I am having a strange issue where i cannot seem to finish logging out of Laravel. It seems to confuse a token with the database connection. What should be `mysql` in this case is `UW6c1Jyh4bhuOw36a5DDKWrjjlaNqes4rPf4U7rst1QcOyhjC8KQaD2ZhCAA`

**EDIT:** Just to note, my `remember_token` column is also never populating

**EDIT 2:** I had not thought to try logging in with "Remember me" selected. I am seeing the same error when I do that.

I went digging into some of these functions and cannot figure out where the confusion is coming from. There couldnt be any issues with my config/database.php file because I am logging in ok once "Remember me" is not checked.

**The logout function:**

```
public function webLogout( ) {
    Auth::logout();
    die('test');
    return redirect('/');
}
```

**The error..**

```
InvalidArgumentException in DatabaseManager.php line 137: Database [UW6c1Jyh4bhuOw36a5DDKWrjjlaNqes4rPf4U7rst1QcOyhjC8KQaD2ZhCAA] not configured.
in DatabaseManager.php line 137
at DatabaseManager->configuration('UW6c1Jyh4bhuOw36a5DDKWrjjlaNqes4rPf4U7rst1QcOyhjC8KQaD2ZhCAA') in DatabaseManager.php line 100
at DatabaseManager->makeConnection('UW6c1Jyh4bhuOw36a5DDKWrjjlaNqes4rPf4U7rst1QcOyhjC8KQaD2ZhCAA') in DatabaseManager.php line 71
at DatabaseManager->connection('UW6c1Jyh4bhuOw36a5DDKWrjjlaNqes4rPf4U7rst1QcOyhjC8KQaD2ZhCAA') in Model.php line 1016
at Model::resolveConnection('UW6c1Jyh4bhuOw36a5DDKWrjjlaNqes4rPf4U7rst1QcOyhjC8KQaD2ZhCAA') in Model.php line 982
at Model->getConnection() in Model.php line 846
at Model->newBaseQueryBuilder() in Model.php line 807
at Model->newQueryWithoutScopes() in Model.php line 490
at Model->save() in EloquentUserProvider.php line 86
at EloquentUserProvider->updateRememberToken(object(User), 'UW6c1Jyh4bhuOw36a5DDKWrjjlaNqes4rPf4U7rst1QcOyhjC8KQaD2ZhCAA') in SessionGuard.php line 534
at SessionGuard->cycleRememberToken(object(User)) in SessionGuard.php line 494
at SessionGuard->logout() in AuthManager.php line 294
at AuthManager->__call('logout', array()) in Facade.php line 221
at AuthManager->logout() in Facade.php line 221
at Facade::__callStatic('logout', array()) in AuthenticateController.php line 60
at Auth::logout() in AuthenticateController.php line 60
at AuthenticateController->webLogout()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AuthenticateController), 'webLogout'), array()) in Controller.php line 55
```